# Sinch sms api and chars with accent mark

Tags: sinch

When I try to send sms with the "ó" char I get a blank char instead.
I have read in the doc that:

> the default alphabet is the GCM 7-bit, but characters in languages such
>   as Arabic, Chinese, Korean, Japanese, or Cyrillic alphabet languages
>   (e.g., Ukrainian, Serbian, Bulgarian, etc.) must be encoded using the
>   16-bit UCS–2 character encoding.

But if I encode the message with UTF-16 (I have read UCS-2 is UTF-16) I get a 40001 error. So, is posible to send special chars with sinch?

Answer (score 0):

GSM-7 and USC-2 are encodings used by the Sinch backend to send the message over smpp. Currently Latin1 (iso-8859-1) is also used, and this is probably why you're getting this missing character since some sms providers do not support it and therefore decode the message using a different decoder. Sinch are removing Latin1 (which result in a shorter encoded short message than USC-2) support and will use USC-2 instead for messages that cannot be encoded with GSM-7 or ASCII.

I'm interested in the 40001 that you're getting. If you're setting the charset to utf-16 on the http request you should not do that. If you're doing something else please post your code (without appKey and secret) so I see more clearly how you generate that error.

Comment: This is the code: 
    $data = array('from'    => $this->from,
       'message' => $message->getContent()
    );  
        
    $recipientNumber = $this->nationalPrefix.$message->getMobileNumber();
        
    $urlToSend= $this->apiHost."/".$this->apiVersion."/".$this->apiSendURL."/".$recipientNumber;
    $this->response = $this->browser->post($urlToSend, $headers, json_encode($data));